# Unable create a shortcuts to create a new file in current location

Tags: macos, shortcuts-app

I have created this shortcut app but when I run it, I don't see any new file created anywhere [image]

Comment: What text are you inputting?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it this way. However getting the path to save in this manner is a bit inefficient.
[image]